# Many-to-many relationship in Java using DAO pattern

Tags: java, mysql, many-to-many, one-to-many, dao

I am creating a web application only using Java and not any framework.

I am at this point where I have to get data from the Database. I am doing this using DAO pattern but I have a problem to understand some logic about relationships (one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many).

To understand my problem better I will explain by taking an exact example.

I have two entities (tables) in the database `User` and `Role`. The entity `User` has attributes `id, name, lastname, username, and password`, and the table `Role` has attributes `id, role, description`.

From this I have the relation that one `User` can have more than one `Role` (so a user can be both a simple user and an admin of the web app), and one `Role` can be in many `User`. From this point I creat another table tha represents many-to-many relationship named `UserRoles` that has attributes `user_id, role_id`.

Now in Java I have a class named `User:

```
public class User
{
    private int id; (with getters and setters)
    private String name; (with getters and setters)
    private String lastname; (with getters and setters)
    private String username; (with getters and setters)
    private String password; (with getters and setters)
    // and two constructors with and without parameters together with toString method
}
```

and the interface named `UserDAO`:

```
public interface UserDAO
{
    public User find(intid);
    public User find(String email, String password);
    public List<User> users();
    public void create(User user);
    public void update(User user);
    public void delete(User user);
    public boolean existEmail(String email);
    public void changePassword(User user);
}
```

I have the class for manipulation with MySQL queries named `UserDAOJDBC`:

```
public class UserDAOJDBC implements UserDAO
{
    private static final String FIND_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?";

    @Override
    public User find(int id) {
        return find(FIND_BY_ID, id);
    }

    private User find(String sql, Object... values){
        User user = null;                 
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = DBConnectionPool.executeQuery(sql, values);
            if(resultSet.next()){
                 user = new User();
                 user.setId(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("id")));
                 user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                 user.setLastname(resultSet.getString("lastname"));
                 user.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
                 user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
            }
            DBConnectionPool.getConnection().close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }        
        return user;
    }

}
```

Now when I want to get `Role` for one `User` what is a better practice?

So far I have this solution:

1) I have to include `Role` in the `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    private int id; (with getters and setters)
    private String name; (with getters and setters)
    private String lastname; (with getters and setters)
    private String username; (with getters and setters)
    private String password; (with getters and setters)
    private List<Role> roles; (with getters and setters)
    // and two constructors with and without parameters together with toString method
}
```

and create in class `UserDAOJDBC` a method named `findWithRoles` that makes the join with the tables as:

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u INNER JOIN userroles as ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
```

and then the second query that goes through results of the previous one:

```
SELECT * FROM role AS r INNER JOIN userroles as ur ON r.id = ur.role_id
```

and from the ResultsSet of this query to populate the array `List<Role> roles`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include Role into the User class (even though you can). It is enough to create the UserRoles table and read the data from it. You should probably create UserRolesDAO class that will implement all the methods for you to find all the roles of a specific user, and all the users to specific role, as well as save new user, role combination and read it back.

I have [an example](https://github.com/asgarov1/DAOPatternExample) on github where I combined Students and Courses in exactly same way using JDBC and DAO pattern so feel free to take a look.

Blog [post](https://programmerpapa.com/dao-layer-with-jdbc/) about dao